# Using menu control with code blocks <% ... %>

Tags: html, asp.net, controls

I am working on adding a menu to my master page.

I created a sitemap and added a control and am getting this error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Followed is my code for the master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/master/template.master.cs" Inherits="template" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Enhancement</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/master.css") %>" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/default.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!-- BEGIN: Sticky Header -->
    <div id="header_container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="headerBar">
                <a href="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx") %>">
                <img src="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/images/logo.png") %>" id="logo" /></a>
                <span id="header_text">Scrum Reports</span>
                <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" CssClass="login_status" LogoutAction="Redirect"
                    LogoutPageUrl="~/default.aspx" />
                <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" CssClass="login_user" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Menu">
            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
            </asp:Menu>
            <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- END: Sticky Header -->
    <!-- BEGIN: Page Content -->
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Main" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Page Content -->
    <!-- BEGIN: Sticky Footer -->
    <div id="footer_container">
        <div id="footer">
            Developed by Application Solutions
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Sticky Footer -->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I found that the following types of code blocks were the culprit:

```
<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/default.css") %>
```

So my question is, how do I get around this? I need the above code for my links to work correctly but I also want to use the menu control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to move the css references out of the header tag into a form tag:

```
<form>
    <link href="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/master.css") %>" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/default.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</form>
```